# Not able to access apache on virtual box from host machine

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualbox

I am not able to access apache installed on the guest machine from the host. Details below. I saw the previous threads and worked on that, but still no luck. So am asking.

- host: windows xp
- guest : centos

In the guest, I could see apache running on 192.168.56.101 and I am able ping this IP from windows(host) machine. But in the browser(host) I am not able to access this apache URL.

Comment: "Not able to access" Does that mean you get nothing from apache at all, or do you get a Forbidden / Not found message rendered by Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured your **iptables** to allow CentOS to accept incoming TCP 80 and TCP 443 traffic? Try adding the following line in your `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

You may also want to try **restoring / resetting the security context** of files in your /var/www/html/ directory by issuing command `restorecon -Rv /var/www/html`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

What version of CentOS are you using?  If 6.x, please ensure selinux disabled.

See file `/etc/selinux/config` ,
Set variable `SELINUX=disabled` ,
Reboot